# Understanding the "Callable" object/things in this code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I having some trouble understanding the "Callable" in this code. There is not much detail about it in my teacher notes.

```
    template <typename Callable>
    double averageTime(int iterations, Callable func) {
         auto sum = 0.;
         for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
             auto before = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
             func();
             std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> milliseconds{std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - before };
             sum += milliseconds.count();
         }
         return sum / iterations;
     }
```

Comment: Did your teacher's notes have anything about templates? `Callable` is just a template type.

Comment: func, is anything you can put () after, and Callable is its type. void hi(){ std::cout << "hi"; } then averageTime(10, hi);

Comment: Mooing Duck - This is the first time I have seen "Callable" thing/object in his class, and my teacher did not mention anything about template in his notes.

Comment: QuentinUK - What is a ""Callable" type in C++? I have tried looking at some references but the left me more question than answer.

Comment: "Callable" in your code is not something built in to C++ - it's just a name your teacher gave up to hint at the expected semantics of the second argument to `averageTime`.  You could change it to "X" and the code would still work the same.  The point of a template is that it can be "instantiated" for various types - it basically gets compiled for combination of template types, doing whatever the `func();` notation normally does for the actual types the caller calls it with.

Comment: Tony Delroy - Thanks, that explanation really help me understand that "Callable." The "Callable" was confusing because my teacher was asking to use a callable function in the HW.

Answer (score 1):

`Callable` is just a name here.

It is a template type parameter, and in this context it is supposed to be something that can be called with no parameters. It may or may not return anything; your code sample doesn't do anything with the result (if any).

Examples:

```
void foo() {std::cout << "Hi!"; } // a function pointer
struct bar { void operator () const { std::cout << "Lo!"; }}; // a struct

double one   = iterations(10, foo);   //
double two   = iterations(10, bar{}); // an object of type bar
double three = iterations(10, []() {std::cout << "Lambda!"; });
```

The salient point is that each of those things passed can be called using function-call syntax.